# Can't change color of first-letter CSS

Tags: html, css

I have one problem, in my div tag i have some text in class "Linkovi" ,but i want to change color of first letter respectively " » " .

How to call class "Linkovi" with first-letter option!

Thanks!

```
<div id="banner5Linkovi">
<p id="QuickLinks"> QUICK LINKS</p>
</br>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!</p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!</p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text! </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text! </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!  </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!  </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!  </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!  </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text! </p> <br/>
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text! </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your first character isn't a letter.

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the » from the content and do this:

```
.Linkovi:before {
    content: '»';
    color: #00f;
}
```

I'd also suggest using `<ul>` and `<li>` if the data will represent a list.

Comment: No problem :)  you can add in any other styles to that pseudo selector too. Compatibility is [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent).

Comment: Ok thank  you :) !

Can you tell me in this picture, is this list with tags <ul> and <li> or is classic <p> tags?

http://oi62.tinypic.com/243ncp2.jpg

How to make spacing between underline and text like on picture?

I'm learning and want to create identically like image up

Comment: It's impossible to tell!  I recommended `<li>`/`<ul>` primarily for semantic correctness.  I quickly made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8vLhzk19/) to look roughly like your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
.Linkovi:first-letter{
  color: red;
}
```

But while ::first-letter won't work because you're you using non-word character, so you may alternatively use pseudo class:

```
.Linkovi:before{
  color: red;
  content: "»"
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hnvv3ov2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `first-letter` with a `&raquo;`. It must be a letter or number, the solution would have to be that you have two different `span` tags inside your element, then target the `&raquo` accordingly:

```
<p class="Linkovi"><span class="red"> » </span><span>&nbsp    This is text!</span></p> <br/>

.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="Linkovi"> » &nbsp    This is text!</p> <br/>
```

You should not be using *that* anyway …

Use

```
<p class="Linkovi">This is text!</p>
```

instead – and use `margin` to give those paragraphs some space in between them, and use a CSS pseudo element with generated content to create the `»` and give it a different color and space from the elements “real” text content.

```css
 p.Linkovi {
   margin-bottom: 1em;
 }
 p.Linkovi:before {
   content: "»";
   color: red;
   padding: 0 20px 0 5px;
 }
```

```html
<p class="Linkovi">This is text!</p>
<p class="Linkovi">This is text!</p>
<p class="Linkovi">This is text!</p>
```